# wkhtmltopdf --page-width and --page-height not working

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf in windows to create a custom sticker, so I need it to render a specific paper size. According to the [documentation](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), I should use `--page-width` and `--page-height` but none of them seems to have any effect, however when I tried `-s` it does change the paper size. This is my command:

```
wkhtmltopdf -g --page-width 10 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 -B 0 sticker.html sticker.pdf
```

I've also tried to set the units like `10px`, `10mm` or `10in`, and tried with different width. No error or message given, everything works but page size is still A4. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally redownloaded and reinstalled the previous version of wkhtmltopdf and it worked. I guess that must have been some kind of installation problem.

Comment: What version are you using? I've uninstalled and re-installed 0.12.6, but I still have this problem

Comment: I find that `--page-height` does work for me _if_ I specify it after `--page-width`

Comment: Thanx JallicleCat!